# How can I execute a function without an event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Solved by @ epascarello**

- Have to execute function without event so that discount can be displayed along with prices at the start without clicking or any other event

> You can see in below snippet that 1st one is running automatic while 2nd one is running on click . Can it possible to run 2nd one as automatic because it solves my most of issues using `this` keyword

**Let me know if you need clarification . Any suggestion or comments will be helpful**.

```js
function discount1() {
  var sendTotal = document.getElementsByClassName("TotalPrice1")[0].innerHTML;
  var send1 = sendTotal.replace(/₹/gi, "");
  var send2 = send1.replace(/,/gi, "");
  var send3 = Number(send2)
  var send = document.getElementsByClassName("DiscPrice1")[0].innerHTML;
  var send4 = send.replace(/₹/gi, "");
  var send5 = send4.replace(/,/gi, "");
  var send6 = Number(send5)
  var rest = ((send3 - send6) / send3) * 100
  document.getElementsByClassName("demo1")[0].innerHTML = rest.toFixed(0) + "% off";
}
discount1();

function discount(rest) {
  var sendTotal = rest.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("TotalPrice")[0].innerHTML;
  var send1 = sendTotal.replace(/₹/gi, "");
  var send2 = send1.replace(/,/gi, "");
  var send3 = Number(send2)
  var send = rest.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("DiscPrice")[0].innerHTML;
   var send4 = send.replace(/₹/gi, "");
  var send5 = send4.replace(/,/gi, "");
  var send6 = Number(send5)
  var rent = ((send3 - send6) / send3) * 100
  rest.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = rent.toFixed(0) + "% off";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="seen" onclick="discount1()">
    <div class="TotalPrice1">&#x20B9;9,728</div>
    <div class="DiscPrice1">&#x20B9;5,435</div>
    <div class="demo1"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div>
  <div class="seen" onclick="discount(this)">
    <div class="TotalPrice">&#x20B9;15,670</div>
    <div class="DiscPrice">&#x20B9;13,785</div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well `discount();` is wrong since you do not pass an element to it......

Comment: so how do i pass , as using `discount1()` it is working fine in 1st part

Comment: because you are not referencing a variable....

Comment: It shows an error.... `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of undefined",`

Comment: document.querySelectorAll(". daad").forEach(discount);

Comment: I already gave you the answer

Comment: In the code.... like you had before you edited it out.

Comment: Where you had `discount();` originally and you deleted it....

Comment: Thank you so much @epascarello it means so much to me .

Comment: Hi, note that you do not need to keep on begging for upvotes. If your post is good, people will upvote them without you asking

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I want to know the method to execute above code without any event , whose answer I got by . I will post a answer myself .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to call your function with the element.

How you get the elements is up to you. querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName, ids, etc.

```
function discount () { /*...*/ }
document.querySelectorAll(".daad").forEach(discount);
```

you can do it inside of the function

```
function discount () {
  document.querySelectorAll(".daad").forEach(function (reed) {
    var saadTotal = reed.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("Total")[0].innerHTML;
    console.log('saadTotal', saadTotal);
    var saadTotal2 = reed.querySelector(".Total").textContent;
    console.log('saadTotal2', saadTotal2);
  } 
}
discount();
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is answer for previous question you can see in question edits**

This is what I needed to do show discount percentage without any event (like onclick or onload) . You can see in below snippet .

```js
function discount(rest) {
  var sendTotal = rest.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("TotalPrice")[0].innerHTML;
  var send1 = sendTotal.replace(/₹/gi, "");
  var send2 = send1.replace(/,/gi, "");
  var send3 = Number(send2)
  var send = rest.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("DiscPrice")[0].innerHTML;
  var send4 = send.replace(/₹/gi, "");
  var send5 = send4.replace(/,/gi, "");
  var send6 = Number(send5)
  var rent = ((send3 - send6) / send3) * 100
  rest.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = rent.toFixed(0) + "% off";
}
document.querySelectorAll(".seen").forEach(discount);;
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="seen" onclick="discount(this)">
    <div class="TotalPrice">&#x20B9;9,728</div>
    <div class="DiscPrice">&#x20B9;5,435</div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<div>
  <div class="seen" onclick="discount(this)">
    <div class="TotalPrice">&#x20B9;15,670</div>
    <div class="DiscPrice">&#x20B9;13,785</div>
    <div class="demo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```